# Building Compile-Time Matrix Expressions

Tags: c++, eigen3

I've just started using Eigen and have read from their documentation that the best performance comes from their lazy evaluation of matrix expressions. Hence, expressions like this are very efficient once evaluated:

```cpp
Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1> a;
a << 0, 1, 2;

Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1> b;
b << 3, 4, 5;

Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1> c;
c << (a + b).sum(),
     (a - b).sum(),
     a.sum();

std::cout << c << std::endl;
```

I ran into a problem when constructing matrices whose column count depends on a template parameter. For example:

```cpp
template <std::size_t w>
auto buildGradient() {
  Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, w> matrix;
  matrix << /* ? */;
  return matrix;
}
```

My first inclination was to use a recursive c++ template do do this.

```cpp
template <std::size_t w, typename Functor>
auto buildGradientExpr(Functor functor) {
  if constexpr (w == 0) {
    return;
  } else if constexpr (w == 1) {
    return functor();
  } else {
    return functor(), buildGradientExpr<w - 1, Functor>(functor);
  }
}
```

But using this leads to runtime errors issued by Eigen, since the expression only has one initializer.

```cpp
template <std::size_t w>
auto buildGradient() {
  Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, w> gradient;
  /* Emits an error about too few coefficients being passed to the initializer. */
  gradient << buildGradientExpr<w>([]() { /* Return 3x1 matrix */ });
  return gradient;
}
```

Here's a complete runnable example.

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>

#include <iostream>

#include <cstddef>

namespace {

template <std::size_t w, typename Functor>
auto buildGradientExpr(Functor functor) {
  if constexpr (w == 0) {
    return;
  } else if constexpr (w == 1) {
    return functor(w);
  } else {
    return functor(w), buildGradientExpr<w - 1, Functor>(functor);
  }
}

template <std::size_t w, typename Functor>
auto buildGradient(Functor functor) {
  Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, w> gradient;
  gradient << buildGradientExpr<w>(functor);
  return gradient;
}

} // namespace

int main() {

  constexpr std::size_t gradient_width = 10;

  auto gradient_functor = [](std::size_t w) {
    return Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>::Constant(float(w) / gradient_width);
  };

  auto gradient = buildGradient<gradient_width>(gradient_functor);

  std::cout << gradient << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Is there a way of constructing matrices with sizes that depend on template parameters, without resorting to a for loop? Nothing against for loops, that's what I'm using in the mean time. I'd just like to know if there's a way to initialize a matrix expression using template loops.

**Edit:*** I updated the example, because the gradient functor was suppose to be returning a vector and not a scalar. The sample problem occurs, though.

Comment: I once did compile time array construction, it may be possible to do it matrices.

Comment: @miszcz2137 Are you talking about Eigen arrays or C++ arrays?

Comment: C++ Arrays, are Eigen array much different?

Comment: @miszcz2137 Yes, unfortunately. C++ template arrays are quite trivial to make but Eigen arrays are somewhat convoluted because they're initialized with a comma operator.

Comment: You could initialize using a `std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<float> >` (requires the master branch of Eigen). Not sure if that really simplifies anything, though.

Comment: @chtz I see that `std::initializer_list` is `constexpr` since C++14. That seems like a good choice. It wasn't really mean to simplify anything, it was mean to improve the compile time optimizations for matrix initialization. Honestly, it is probably premature optimization. Either way, if you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @chtz Perhaps give an example, too. Thinking about this a bit more, I'm not quite sure if this is actually possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your issue here, and you can use c++11, a possible solution could be the following:

(a) extend the `Eigen::Matrix` class as explained [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_Plugins.html) to include the constructor from `std::initializer_list<T>`:

```
// File "Eigen_plugin.h"
template<class T>
Matrix(std::initializer_list<T> elems) : Base()
{
    Base::_check_template_params();

    int idx = 0;
    for(auto el : elems)
        coeffRef(idx++) = el;
}
```

(b) define your `buildGradient` function using [variadic templates](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/):

```
// File main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

template<class... Args>
Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, sizeof...(Args)/3> buildGradient(Args&&... args)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) % 3 == 0, "Wrong number of elements");
    return Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, sizeof...(Args)/3>{ args... };
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << buildGradient(1.0,2.0,3.0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << buildGradient(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0) << std::endl;
}
```

*Note*

As explained in the first link, to make this compile you need to define the preprocessor variable `EIGEN_MATRIX_PLUGIN` to point at the absolute path of your plugin file:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -D EIGEN_MATRIX_PLUGIN=\"path-to-Eigen_plugin.h\"
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. I ended up just using C++14, which allows for constexpr for-loops.